# What is the reason for the error ' PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied ' when running the django server

Tags: python, django, permission-denied

When I try to run the Django server, the server runs properly, but I also get the following error and my developing website does not load properly. What could be the problem?

```
File "C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 183, in finish_response
    for data in self.result:
  File "C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\wsgiref\util.py", line 37, in __next__
    data = self.filelike.read(self.blksize)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

Comment: You probably don't have the required permissions to read the file... If you have root access try to elevate the permissions of this file (`sudo chmod +r file`)

Answer (score 2):

There may be few reasons for that

1. Literally your account doesn't have proper permission to access it
2. Where the folder described doesn't exist
3. Where a folder is described instead of file

So I think you can find the reason if check above items

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand where the problem is. When I enter the domain 127.0.0.1: 8000 with Chrome browser, I encounter an error, but not with Firefox.